Can't change aperture on cannon 1
I have a mark D111 and when I set her in manual I can't change the aperture. Can anyone help and also what does exp SIM mean . These are new things that have just happened to me .

Do you mean Canon EOS-1D Mark III?

Exp Sim: https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/s/article/ART128241

What lens are you using?

Welcome to Stack Exchange Photography! Please take the tie to be as precise an thorough when asking questions - otherwise we will start to guess things instead of helping you.

The most common reason for your Aperture “problem” is that your rear control is locked to prevent unwanted accidental movement once your aperture is set.

“exp SIM” is unrelated, but is only used when using the rear LCD to compose your image before shooting. Using the rear screen to compose is called  “Live View” and exp SIM will show you on the rear screen what your current exposure setting will look like before you take the photo.
